# How does firebase dynamic link analytics capture events like APP_INSTALL/APP_FIRST_OPEN?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

How is firebase able to capture events like APP_INSTALL/APP_FIRST_OPEN from dynamic links
Have they setup exclusive callbacks for google services internally or can a third party link shortening service capture similar events?

[image: work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have they setup exclusive callbacks for google services internally

Yes, there is integration with Play services on Android.  Play will broadcast information to the app about the installation and launch when coming from a dynamic link.

You might want to read the documentation about [Google Play Install Referrers](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer) to get a better idea how it works.